# Post request data reading intermitently failing in server side after publishing

Tags: c#, ajax, post, recaptcha

I have an Ajax request from an Javascript code to a C# Web Api where I'm trying to validate reCaptcha information before actually processing the request. When I test it locally from VS2015 Community (IIS Express under localhost:port/) works like a charm but when I deploy it on either my test server (IIS on a separate machine under machine/folder) or even in my local test IIS (in localhost but under locahost/folder/) the request just fails with code 500 so I'm getting my own "Server error" message

This is my API method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Thing> GetThings(string parameter1, string parameter2)
    {
        List<Thing> ListThings = new List<Thing>();
        try
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            bool recaptchaValidation = false;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    dynamic captchaResponse = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, typeof(ReCaptchaEncodedResponse));
                    recaptchaValidation = ReCaptcha.ReCaptcha.Validate(captchaResponse.captchaResponse, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptchaPrivateKey"]) == "True" ? true : false;
                }
            }
            if (!recaptchaValidation)
                return null;
         ... Code for getting the list of things...
         return ListThings;
         }
         ... Code for processing exceptions ... 
    }
```

this is the JS where I'm requesting it

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (!captchaResponse) { 
        refreshCatcha();
        alert("Wrong captcha");
        return;
    }
    $("input").prop('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    $http.post('api/ManageThingsApi/GetThings/' + $scope.Thing.Param1 + "/" + $scope.Thing.Param2,
        { "captchaResponse": captchaResponse }).success(function (data) {
        if (data === null) {
            refreshCatcha();
            alert("Not found");
        }
        else if (data.length === 0) {
            refreshCatcha();
            alert("Not found");

        }
        else {
            $scope.Data = data;
            $location.path('/ShowThings');
            $("#Search").css({ 'display': "none" });

        }
        $("input").prop('disabled', ''); 
        }).error(function (error) {
            $("input").prop('disabled', '');
            alert("Server error");
    });
}
```

This is my ReCaptchaEncodedResponse class

```
public class ReCaptchaEncodedResponse
{
    public string captchaResponse { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure but I'm starting to believe the problem lies somewhere between the POST parameters (in body as I've read) and the Request.Content in server.

So whats wrong?

---

**Updated:** Changed the API method to make it receive all info from post only and removed reading request body that was ugly.

Modified API method:

```
    public List<Thing> GetThings([FromBody]SearchRequest srequest)
    {
        List<Thing> ListThings = new List<Thing>();
        bool recaptchaValidation = false;
        recaptchaValidation = ReCaptcha.ReCaptcha.Validate(srequest.ValidationToken, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptchaPrivateKey"]) == "True" ? true : false;
        if (!recaptchaValidation)
            return null;
       ...
     }
```

modified JS:

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    $scope.captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (!$scope.captchaResponse) {
        alert("Captcha verification required");
        return;
    }
    $("input").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    var requestData = {
        Param1: $scope.Thing.Param1,
        Param2: $scope.Thing.Param2,
        ValidationToken: $scope.captchaResponse
    };
    $http.post('api/ManageThingsApi/GetThings',
                requestData, 'json').success(function (data) {
        if (data === null) {
            grecaptcha.reset();
            alert("Not found");
        }
        else if (data.length === 0) {
            grecaptcha.reset();
            alert("Not found");

        }
        else {
            $scope.Data = data;
            $location.path('/ShowThings');
            $("#Search").css({ 'display': "none" });

        }
        $("input").prop('disabled', '');
        }).error(function (error) {
            $("input").prop('disabled', '');
            alert("Server error");
    });
};
```

Parameter class:

```
public class SearchRequest {
        public string Param1 { get; set; }
        public string Param2 { get; set; }
        public string ValidationToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Again works like a charm from VS2015 IIS Express, error 500 from local IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

The error was (as usual) coming from the most unexpected, silly and simple place where you almost never check.

Both codes worked fine but I forgot to setup the **proxy** for the **server** to connect to Google in order to validate the token.

See, the **first** request to Google comes from the **client** (in javascript code), therefore it uses the *browser's proxy settings* which are usually correct. Now the **second** request to Google comes from the **server** (in C# code) so it will use the *server's configuration and credentials* to connect.

When testing using **local IIS Express** it also uses the same configuration as the client due to IIS Express runs on the **logged user's credentials and configuration**. But a **standard IIS** itself normally uses **it's own user credentials** to run so there is no proxy configuration to it.

Modified (and working!) code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public List<Thing> GetThings(ValidatedRequest requestParams)
    {
        List<Thing> ListThings = new List<Thing>();
        if (requestParams == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unauthorized");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestParams.ValidationToken))
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unauthorized");
        JObject obj = null;
        try
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            var googleVerificationURL = string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}&remoteip={2}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gReCaptchaPrivateKey"], requestParams.ValidationToken, remoteIpAddress);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyAddress"].Trim()))
            {
                wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyAddress"].Trim());
                wc.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUsername"].Trim(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyPassword"]);
            }
            var result = wc.DownloadString(googleVerificationURL);
            wc.Dispose();
            obj = JObject.Parse(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to connect to reCaptcha", ex);
        }
        if(obj == null || !(bool)obj.SelectToken("success"))
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unauthorized");
        ... Rest of the code ... 
     }
```

As you can see I also created variables for proxy address, proxy user and proxy pass inside the AppSettings section of my **web.config** (arguably there might be security concerns here)

Also did minor cosmetic changes to the SearchRequest class that now has become ValidatedRequest class

```
    public class ValidatedRequest
    {
        public string ValidationToken { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
    }
```

That's it, Sayonara!